# Appending CURL STDOUT to printf

Tags: linux, bash, curl, printf

I'm trying to append the percentage complete output to end of printf, but curl keeps replacing the line completely. Any suggestions?

```
printf "${servicename[$i]} - "
curl -# BLAH
```

The output would look like this:

```
Something - ################## 100%
Otherthing - ################## 100%
```

If I could show the percent as it went up, that would be even better.
I'm, ok with it just displaying when it's done at 100%. I know printf doesn't do line breaks by default, so I figured this would work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: curl is likely clearing the line so that it can write the percentage new each time it changes it. That's probably the problem. Piping the curl output through `sed` might let you do what you want (but will use multiple lines instead of just one most likely).

Comment: Any idea how I can do the opposite then? Prepend the array resource curl is going for?

Comment: I don't know that you can control what curl prints for the progress bar.

Comment: I think the sed idea may work. Using curl to pull down individual resources via an API.

Comment: You can use `-w` to control what curl spits out after each file is done. If that's of use.

Comment: Have you tried wget?  It has a couple of options to manage the progress bar, but still I don't think you can manage the output to exactly the extent you're looking for.  Still, you may be able to get the output you're looking for with the built-in methods that are made available to you.